# Msg 14027, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_addarticle [table] does not exist in the current database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

Before setting up SQL Server snapshot replication, I backed up the database from ServerA and restored it to ServerB. Both servers are running SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1.

In trying to setup snapshot replication from ServerA to ServerB using the GUI, I get the following error:

> Msg 14027, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_addarticle, Line
>   582 [dbo].[SYSCOLUMNS] does not exist in the current database.

Yes, that is the name of the table and it is indeed a user table. I ran the setup from ServerA which is the Publisher. The collation is the same between the tables on both servers. If I remove that table as an article, the replication is setup just fine.

I've searched the web on this and I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Answer generated from a comment left by the question author*</sub>

It was determined that it's not possible to replicate tables that are using the same names as system tables/views such as `dbo.syscolumns` or `dbo.sysobjects`.